# Geoprocessing>Merge and arcpy.Merge_management() producing different results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge

In ArcMap 10.2.1 I have three feature classes in geodatabase "MyGDB.gdb".  Let's call the feature classes "A", "B", and "C" respectively.  I am merging the feature classes using Geoprocess > merge.  Here are the exact steps:

1. Geoprocessing>Merge
2. Select feature classes "A", "B", and "C" as the input datasets
3. Save the output dataset as "Merged" in "MyGDB.gdb"

After creating the merged dataset, I am running the following code in a python script to count the number of data points in each feature class and also in the merged data set:

```
lyrfile1 = 'C:\\ArcGIS\\Python\\MyGDB.gdb\\Merged'
lyrfile2 = 'C:\\ArcGIS\\Python\\MyGDB.gdb\\A'
lyrfile3 = 'C:\\ArcGIS\\Python\\MyGDB.gdb\\B'
lyrfile4 = 'C:\\ArcGIS\\Python\\MyGDB.gdb\\C'

result1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile1).getOutput(0)) 
result2 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile2).getOutput(0)) 
result3 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile3).getOutput(0)) 
result4 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile4).getOutput(0)) 


print result1
print result2
print result3
print result4
```

The results are as follows:
151983
19394
75578
57011

This is good and expected.  Since the three feature classes are merged, I would expect to see that the merged data set has the same number of data points as each individual feature class combined,, and it does (57011+75578+19394=151983).

Here is where the problem starts:  when I try to merge the datasets using arcpy.Merge_management() and then use arcpy.GetCount to count the datapoints, only a fraction of the datapoints are returned (57011).  Here is the code:

```
fClasses = []   #initialize array to hold feature classes   

#Set counter for loop
i=0

#Loop through MyGDB.gdb and add each feature class name to array
try:
        # Get a list of the featureclasses in the gdb
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    #Iterate
    for fc in fcs:   
        print fc
        fClasses.append(fc)
        i = i+1 

except Exception as err:
    arcpy.AddError(err)
    print err



#Now that we have a list of all feature classes, attempt to merge them into one class
try:
    arcpy.Merge_management([fClasses], "Merged")
    print "merge:  SUCCESS."

        #Count number of points in newly created merged dataset
    result1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("Merged").getOutput(0)) 
    print result1

except Exception as err:
    arcpy.AddError(err)
    print "merge:  FAIL."
    print err
```

This returns only 57011 points, versus the 151983 points in the merge file creating using Geoprocessing > Merge.  What am I missing here?

Comment: could you share your script, preferably a highly simplified version?

Comment: Agree with Kevin, you need to upload your code if you want help.

Comment: Totally agree, at least some code is required otherwise we're just guessing... and I *hate* guessing games.

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste the code from when you "manually create a merged dataset using Geoprocessing > Merge in the ArcMap program" by going to the **Geoprocessing | Results** window and using **Copy As Python Snippet**.

Comment: I think you need to do more editing of your Question.  I would focus on making it clear that you have performed the Merge using two different methods on the same data and are expecting to see the same number of features in the output.  I would list the precise steps you used to do each method because at the moment it sounds like you may have used **File > Add Data > Add XY Data** but have not explicitly said so.  Also be sure to include the version number of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using.

Comment: From what I can understand, I'm having the same issue (using 10.1): I have performed one merge in ArcMap (geoprocessing) and one in a script using arcpy.Merge_management(), and the number of objects I get from the script merge is not the same as the one I get from the ArcMap merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just remove the square brackets around fClasses in `arcpy.Merge_management([fClasses], "Merged")`. There are already brackets included in that fClasses list variable. For a reason that is not clear to me, adding these extra brackets selects only the last feature class in the fClasses list.